# Prototype using Square Brackets (Vanilla JS solution only)

Tags: javascript, prototype

How can I apply a prototype to constructor function using (square brackets). I don't want to use dot notation because it does not evaluate the variable but rather returns the variable name and I want the prototype to be more dynamic. Below is what I am trying to achieve but I can't get it to work.

```
var prototyper = function(constructor_name, prototype_name, data)
{
     main[constructor_name][__prototype__][prototype_name] = new Function(data);
}
```

prototyper("classify","alert_classification","alert(this.classification)");

Comment: You should almost never use `new Function`.

Comment: You seem to want `__prototype__ === "prototype"`, or just use `main[…].prototype[…] = …`

Comment: "*I don't want to use dot notation*" - can you elaborate? It seems to be exactly what you actually want. And you'd be able to get your function to work with it, don't you?

Comment: @Bergi I'm curious why you said I should almost never use new Function. It's safer than invoking eval and I can use it as long as I don't pass parameters to it directly. I use arguments array to obtain the parameters.

Comment: Does main[...].prototype[...] work? I have never seen that but I will definitely try it.

Comment: It's still slower and harder to debug than function expressions, so you should avoid it when you don't need it. And as you say yourself, using parameters is awkward in your particular usage.

Comment: @Bergi If you try to do main.constructor_name.__prototype it is going to try and find the property constructor_name not the constructor_name's actual value, that's why I insisted on bracket notation rather than dot.

Comment: You want bracket notation for the variable properties (`…[constructor_name]` and `…[prototype_name]`) but dot notation for the constant property `….prototype`. You will need to mix them. Sorry if the use of ellipsis above was unclear

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? I think I already tried it to no avail. I might be messing something up. Feel free to use jQuery if it's easier.

Comment: If it only has to evaluate the new Function once and then it is stored in memory isn't it worth it to use new Function?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Please provide the fiddle where you tried it and it didn't work (or [edit] a [mcve] into your question). No, jQuery doesn't make anything easier here.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference for the function call, but for the function definition. No, it's not worth it, as there is no gain but only disadvantages. Don't treat code as text unless you have to.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thomanat/Ly51pxyk/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b5fsbvm3/

Comment: Thanks, put it in the solutions so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want bracket notation for the variable properties (`…[constructor_name]` and `…[prototype_name]`) but dot notation for the constant property `….prototype`. You will need to mix them into

```
function prototyper(constructor_name, method_name, fn) {
    main[constructor_name].prototype[method_name] = fn;
}
```

([jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b5fsbvm3/))